# How to auto-layout view in Playground LiveView

Tags: swift, swift-playground

I have a Live View and a view on which I work on, and I would like this last one to resize according to LiveView dimensions (i.e.: in portrait the LiveView occupies only the top-half of the screen, in landscape only the right-half).
I read that NSLayoutCostraints don't work in playground, so how should I do it?